# Upload PDF with Guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle6

I have a remote PDF like https://mypdf.pdf and I want to send to another service.

my Guzzle code is:

```
 $responseClient = $this->clientGuzzle->request(
                'POST', "url", [ 
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name' => $name,
                        'filename' => $name,
                        'contents' => fopen($pdf,'rb'),
                        'headers' => [
                            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => "binary",
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ]
);
```

My `fopen` is false.

Comment: Does the PDF in the link exist? Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled? Are there any notices or warnings?

Answer (score 1):

If `fopen` returns `false` then the question isn't related to Guzzle. Check your file and permissions.